# Unable to load three in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am trying to use useGLTF to load a model but it gives me an error:

```js
"use client";
import { OrbitControls, PreLoad, useGLTF} from "@react-three/drei";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Model = () => {
    const modelFile = useGLTF("./thinker/scene.gltf");

    return (
        <div>Model</div>
    );
}

export default Model;
```

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.99.0",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.15.16",
    "@types/three": "^0.161.2",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "three": "^0.161.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

The folder structure:
[image: Folders]

I expected the route to be correct but it says it cannot find the route url
[image: Error]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are importing `"./thinker/scene.gltf"` but I didn't see your `thinker` directory in your `Components` directory. Is `thinker` dir in your `public` dir? Have you try with `"/thinker/scene.gltf"`?

Comment: I have a thinker in puclic and "/thinker/scene.gltf" gives the same error, I have also tried to put thinker in componets but it does not work